# What is the point of using "rm -P"?

Tags: unix, gnu, rm

Man page contains the following info regarding `-P` argument:

> -P Overwrite regular files before deleting them.  Files are overwritten three times, first with the byte pattern 0xff, then 0x00, and then 0xff again, before they are deleted.

What is a typical use case for using this argument parameter? Secure delete comes to mind but is it really that secure to simply overwrite a file 3 times?

Comment: no, it's not that secure, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant or just the same. This technique has zero effect when applied to a file stored on ZFS or btrfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36870/whats-the-purpose-of-rm-p) can answer to your question.

> There is a technique called residual information retrieval that can
>   read data that was deleted based on the idea that when the drive is
>   magnetized in order to store data other parts that are close to the
>   data is also affected by this and it should be possible to re-read
>   data this way ... this is though a costly technique, but use it if you
>   are paranoid ;)
>
> By writing data 3 times (in this case) the parts next to the track on
>   the drive should be re-set as well in order to make it impossible to
>   re-read this way.

Comment: Thanks! I really used SO search and google prior to posting my question here